# How do I have my computer remember a processes's priority?

Tags: process, windows-8.1

I've noticed that by increasing `OpenVPN-gui-1.0.3.exe` and `openvpn.exe`'s process priority, I'm able to get faster speeds through my VPN.

However, stopping the program then turning it back on results in them resetting back to `normal` instead of `high`.

How do I have my computer remember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Prio! It's a free application that allows you to do this, and it's always worked for me!

EDIT: And it integrates into the task manager.